# I have one case, where numpy.where() does not work as expected. Where is my error?

Tags: python, numpy, nifti, mri

I have a binary segmentation map as output from a neural network (niftii format) and want to maintain only the biggest island, to get rid of unwanted false positives.

I am able to achieve this with:

```
import nibabel as nib
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import label

vol = 'PATH_TO_VOLUME'
elements_in_biggest_island = 0
biggest_index = 0
aNii = nib.load(vol)
a = aNii.get_fdata()

s = np.ones((3,3,3), dtype = 'uint8')

labelled_array, num_features = label(a, structure=s)

for i in range (1, num_features + 1):
    tempArray = labelled_array
    if (np.count_nonzero(tempArray == i) > elements_in_biggest_island):
        elements_in_biggest_island = np.count_nonzero(tempArray == i)
        biggest_index = I

print("Biggest Island was at index ", biggest_index, " with a total of ", elements_in_biggest_island, " members.")

labelled_array[labelled_array == biggest_index] = 1.0
labelled_array[labelled_array < biggest_index ] = 0.0
labelled_array[labelled_array > biggest_index] = 0.0

ni_img = nib.Nifti1Image(labelled_array, aNii.affine)
nib.save(ni_img, f'PATH_TO_PROCESSED_VOL')
```

But the "thresholding" is very inefficient. In another application I work with numpy.where(), which generates a good speedup compared to the shown way of thresholding.
My approach was, to remove the array[array>I] == x lines by:

```
labelled_array = np.where(labelled_array==biggest_index, 1, 0)
```

This exact line works perfectly in another application, but here I only get a black 3D volume, which does not work for me.
Is anybody able to point out the mistake, that I have made?

Comment: The `where` is only as good as the condition: `labelled_array==biggest_index`

Comment: I don't really get the point of your answer, to be honest @hpaulj

Comment: I don't know what is the aim of the code, what is `nifti` and …. If `np.where` was working on another example, perhaps this condition `labelled_array==biggest_index` is not satisfying **at all** in any pairs in this example. That's all I know about probable cause of your problem. To improve your runtime, perhaps using libraries such as `numba` (`njit`) could be helpful.

Comment: Well, I made no changes to the code, whatsoever..but after a good old restart it just worked as expected...   three hours of work for nothing, because a restart fixed it..